# ExpandableListView center one single header (cellForRowAt equivalent)

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` and my problem is that it doesn't quite work like tables in iOS. I want to center one particular header's title and with `cellForRowAt` in iOS that was simple as I could hold some kind of reference to each cell/ section header.

Now I can't seem to find anything like this on Android. Does ExpandableListView not allow that?

Thanks

Comment: You want to have only one header? Return only one header and have all of your items be children for it.

Comment: No, I have multiple headers but there is one that has to be different

Comment: Just return a different view for that one, and check the type of convertView parameter before you re-cycle it

Comment: Wow, I didn't find the Adapter that I've created days ago, I thought there is only a private adapter available, that was stupid haha, thanks so much